# Find files whose name is 4 characters long

Tags: shell, find, ls, filenames, wildcards

I would like to find files whose name has only 4 characters.

Example, there are three files under `/tmp`:

```
$ ls /tmp
txt
file
linux
```

Output should only show `file` because it only has 4 characters.

Comment: If you want to print also hidden files make use of brace expansion: `echo /tmp/{.,?}???`.

Comment: What? No `grep` based solution yet?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It's not the best tool for the job. `grep` matches lines of text, but not all filenames are guaranteed to be single lines of text.

Comment: I wonder what the answers would look like if you wanted to list only file names of length 140 chars...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.

Comment: Also, *bytes* or *characters*?  `beta` in UTF-8 is 4 characters and 4 bytes long, while `bétá` is 4 characters and 6 bytes....

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the `?` wildcard for file globbing:

```
ls -d /tmp/????
```

This will print all files and directories whose filename is 4-char long.

As suggested by @roaima, the `-d` flag will prevent `ls` to display the content of subdirectories that match the pattern.

Comment: Thanks It works!  I have another question how to find the file in sub-directory without /tmp

Comment: Please open a separate question for this.

Comment: Note that this won't list hidden file.

Comment: Use `ls -d` to avoid expansion of any directory matching `/tmp/????`

Comment: @roaima Good point, added it to the answer.

Comment: To include filenames beginning with a dot, set the `dotglob` shell option before this (e.g. `shopt -s dotglob`; to unset it afterwards, use `shopt -u dotglob`).

Comment: @frostschutz. Why is using [find] sub-optimal? +10 votes suggests there's a good reason

Comment: @user913 if simple globbing does the same job, find is overkill. nothing wrong with it otherwise

Answer (score 11):

List files in `/tmp` only:

```
cd /tmp
find . ! -name . -prune -path './????' -type f
```

List files in `/tmp` recursively:

```
find /tmp -path '*/????' -type f
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
find /tmp -type f -print| awk -F/ ' length($NF)  == 4 '
```

What `awk` does:

- Using `/` as field separator,
- Finding filename `$NF` (last field)
- Computing `length`
- And check if value is 4, then print it.

Comment: This won't work if filename contains newline.

Comment: @cuonglm can file name have new line?

Comment: @Ooker: Yes, try `touch a$'\n'b`

Answer (score 4):

This seems to me like the most straightforward way to find a file of four bytes:

```
find /tmp -type f -size 4c
```

Edit: to find a file **name** of four bytes:

```
find /tmp -type f -name '????'
```

Comment: Judging by the example given in the question, OP is looking at file names not contents.

Comment: Ah, of course, not a file of four bytes but a file name of four bytes. That makes sense.

Comment: This will also match `/tmp/somelongpathname/fred`, which doesn't match the glob `/tmp/????`

Comment: It is supposed to. /tmp/???? only finds files immediately under /tmp.

Comment: Can use `-maxdepth` arg to restrict to immediate entries of `/tmp`.  The original question is unclear on the requirement.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a `perl` (5.10 or newer) solution:

```
perl -E 'say for </tmp/????>;'
```

A slightly more flexible version where you can specify the desired length:

```
perl -E 'my $w = "?" x shift; say for </tmp/$w>;' 4
```

Answer (score 3):

"/tmp/" takes 5 characters. That's why there is "9" (5+4) in test

```
for i in /tmp/* ;
  do [ "${#i}" -eq 9 ] && printf %s\\n "$i";
done
```

or

```
for i in /tmp/* ;
  do i="${i#/tmp/}"; # to get rid of /tmp/
  [[ "${#i}" -eq 4 ]] && printf %s\\n "$i"; # there is 4 in test!
done
```

FWIW. It does not fail on newline (@cuonglm), 
can be easilly converted to list only 140 character long file names (@don_crissti).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using bash, you can do the following:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
filearray=(/tmp/**/????)
```

This will put the list of files you want in an array `filearray`.  Newlines (and other exotic characters) in the filename will be handled correctly.

Setting globstar enables `**` in glob patterns to match across subdirectories, giving the required recursive search.

Setting nullglob simply causes the expansion to expand to nothing if there are no matches.  Otherwise it will expand to itself which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As globbing is done by the shell, there is even no need to call ls or find, echo does the trick:

```
$ echo /tmp/????
/tmp/file
$
```

Only thing is, if there is no file whose name is 4 characters long, it will just print

```
/tmp/????
```

You might want a one-liner bash script that checks this and also prints one file per line:

```
pattern=/tmp/????? ; for f in $pattern ; do if [ $f != "$pattern" ] ; then echo $f ; fi ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
ls /tmp | grep -e '^.\{4\}$'
```

for a `grep` based answer.

Comment: This won't work if filename contains newline

Comment: @cuonglm if your going to be pedantic about newlines, at least apply it evenly across all answers to a question. Any globbing with ?(s) is susceptible to this defect.

Comment: I mention this in all answers which won't handle newline in filename. Globbing doesn't have this trouble.

Comment: but the answer by dr01 also fails on this as \n is counted as two characters where as it is actually only one.

Comment: @joeLovick In *nix platforms a newline is a single linefeed character.

Comment: yes, but when i run your code in zsh it doesnt match across that single character, hence   ls /tmp/??????  returns /tmp/tes\nt

Comment: @joeLovick: You created file with literal `\n`, not newline

Comment: never parse `ls` for anything

Comment: `ls -q | grep -E '^.{4}$'` should take care of those file names with funky chars (though they'll appear as question marks in the output).